# Heater close to monitor - any potential dangers?

Tags: display, overheating

In my apartment, I have no choice but to have my office and thus my screen(but thankfully not the computer tower itself) like 5cm from the wall heater, like this one: [image]

Is it possible that this heater, when working for ~3 hours per day with the monitor open to cause issues with the operation of the monitor?

Answer (score 1):

(Some information about the monitor would have been useful.)

In general, there should be no problem, unless you use the wall heater for boiling
your coffee.

Monitors are made to work in normal temperatures.
So if you can stand the heat, so can your monitor.

Comment: I'd temper that argument with 'if you put a jumper on & sit with your back leaning against the radiator, how long could you stand it for?" If the answer is anything under "an hour" I'd be worried for the screen's health, long-term. Those things can easily reach 60°C surface temperature [in fact that's the recommended water temp for a semi-sealed system.]